# Flexbox for fixed-height container that wraps items and has dynamic width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a use case that *feels* like flexbox CSS should be able to handle, but I can't get it working properly. I'm not sure if this use case is beyond what flexbox can handle or not, so I'm looking for advice. (I wrote JavaScript that does what I need, but I'm looking at this to see if a pure CSS implementation is feasible.)

I have one container div that will contain 1 or more items. Each of the contained items has a fixed width and height. The container div has a fixed height, but should only take as much width as it takes to contain its items. The items should be laid out within the div from top to bottom, and should wrap to a new column when they "fill up" the previous column.

Here's some sample HTML that I'm using to test:

```
<div class="my-container">
    <div class="my-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 15</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 16</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 17</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 18</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 19</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 20</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 21</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 22</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 23</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 24</div>
    <div class="my-item">Item 25</div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS I'm using to test:

```
    .my-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);
        padding: 15px;
        height: 600px;
    }

    .my-item {
        width: 250px;
        height: 25px;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
```

Note that the values for the widths and heights are arbitrary here and may be changed. But the items will always have a fixed width/height and the container will always have a fixed height.

With the CSS above, the items do wrap to a new column correctly, but **the container div fills the entire width of the viewport**. I need the container div to only be wide enough to contain its items.

If I change the display attribute for my-container from "flex" to "inline-flex", the container width shrinks down, but isn't wide enough to show more than the first column, with subsequent columns not fully visible.

This may be one of those catch 22 situations. The items have fixed size, but need to flow into columns based on the container's height. And the container needs to take its width from the number of columns that its items have flowed into.

I also looked into CSS grid to see if that might be a possibility, but it sounds like you have to know the number of columns in advance for that to work, and I won't know that. The number of columns depends on the size of the items and the height of the container.

Can flexbox CSS solve this problem? If not, any other CSS-based approaches? I already have a JavaScript implementation that does this, I would just prefer to have a pure CSS implementation if that is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grid's autofill property, so you don't need to know the number of columns.

```
  .my-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(45px, 1fr));
    background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);
    padding: 15px;
    height: 600px;
    width: fit-content;
}

.my-item {
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/92sak0zc/6/